# How to manually calculate AUC and Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning

How to calculate AUC using some formula? What are the parameters required and what formula to use.

For accuracy, $$ \frac{TP+TN}{Total} $$ is this right way to calculate AUC?

Comment: These are Confusion Matrix metrics, you can see the formula for every metric in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)

Answer (score 1):

> For accuracy, TP+TN/total is it right way to calculate?

If your problem is binary classification, then yes.

> How to calculate AUC using some formula? What are the parameters
>   required and what formula to use?

Check this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145566/how-to-calculate-area-under-the-curve-auc-or-the-c-statistic-by-hand).

Comment: What can be the difference in range of value of AUC and accuracy? (0 to 1) Which one is more? and  using tp,tn,fp,fn  can we calculate AUC without drawing roc curve?

Comment: @Shivanya Those would be better as new questions than as comments, but AUC goes from [0.5, 1], with larger values being "better". You do not need to draw an ROC curve to calculate AUC, though it is useful for comparing different decision thresholds.